# How to make a separate column of cells in one column corresponding to cells in other in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, dcast

I have a data table called "vsample.csv" that looks like this:
[vsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4t97.png)

I need to make a new data set which should look like this:
[vsample_answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJZgi.png)
can't really figure out a syntax in R. Can someone help please?
Thanks

Comment: You can use `dcast` from `reshape2` or `data.table` i.e. `dcast(vsample, Subject ~Response.Congruency.with.Cartoon, value.var = "Congruency.percentage")`

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a ton Akrun!

Comment: Thank you for merging the question into the existing threads. I didn't know the right vocabulary.

Comment: Hello Akrun, how do I do the same if I have to do the thing with another column that will have E and H. And the resulting new data table should have E_C, E_IC, H_C and H_IC?
The command with Subject~ .(column1, column2) doesn't work.